Cannot release new app version to playstore due to issues with the old app version
We have an old Android app, last released in 2019, and I have completely redeveloped the app using React Native. Additionally, we no longer have access to the old source code. I want to release the new version as an update to the old version so that our customers can directly install the new version via an update.
Unfortunately, this isn't working. Whenever I try to release the new version for testing or even for production, the release gets rejected because the old 2019 version uses a non-compliant SDK version. I don’t want to use the old version at all; I’d rather just remove it. I'm stuck and can't find a way to release my new app because the old app always leads to a rejection of the release.
Can someone please help? :)

What SDK is the old code written in?
Usually it's enough to just release the new source code with the matching package Id on the store and KeyStore file (signing certificate), then Google takes care of the rest.
If Google is complaining about a non compliant SDK, it means it's an issue with its dependencies.
Can you check if the old SDK is written by Tencent? Or any other Chinese Company? If so, this might be the reason why.
Google has security restrictions against anything made from China. You can thank your Old Uncle Sam for that.
